# Docker Cannot Resolve Hostname

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

## I am trying to link my containerized VueJS frontend with my containerized Spring Boot API backend, with great difficulty.

Whenever I try to make an HTTP request to my API using the container name, I get the following.

> OPTIONS http://api:4505/user/sign-in net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Here is my `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  api:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/darragh.oflah/api:latest
    container_name: api
    ports:
      - "4505:4505"
    links:
      - mongodb
  web:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/darragh.oflah/web:latest
    container_name: web
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    links:
      - api
```

Here what I get when I run `sudo docker network inspect tmp_default`

So it would seem that the network is set up correctly

```
[
    {
        "Name": "tmp_default",
        "Id": "75ab7c89cb5a80aa7eddd7c5a3f7f4aafb911cfe96a923ad3db2219552366fd7",
        "Created": "2020-02-04T16:55:49.131485109Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "6ae3db08be2ed22245a173a677ae1b0f28eca878aa84e43744a320589cbda5af": {
                "Name": "mongo",
                "EndpointID": "b399bb72f28b6d47a93927712a665dcc725d27a6ba2ee432e715db00c9cbc835",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "fa7e4066e436181ce2991e048790f8de518af31fb97cf9351316ff8f41824449": {
                "Name": "api",
                "EndpointID": "bf8d071683bfa4ecbd215f3dd534d0e278702ed4377552ef242e5c65b01c3fa1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "fb544ef5389afd74d53f45d6de968008632b65340f161527a9c7aa4214aa7674": {
                "Name": "web",
                "EndpointID": "2dc3e8a452c241916a2e9f7e25b33ee7997fe2d25ec3543e5d34e888e50d905c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "tmp",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.21.2"
        }
    }
]
```

In the net work tab, the request is saying failed, which would indicate to me that the request is failing to leave the container at all.

## [image]

Comment: So you're running "web" in a container but the browser is running on the host machine right? Therefore the browser running on the host machine won't understand how to resolve `http://api:4505/user/sign-in`. If you type `http://api:4505/user/sign-in` into the browser url bar I'd imagine you'd also get an error.

Comment: Browser is running on my machine, and the docker-compose is being run on an AWS ubuntu instance. I thought docker works by creating DNS for each of your containers so you can just reference them by name

Comment: You can reference by name within the same network, but the browser running on your machine is not in the docker network.

Comment: Right so I must use the IP of the AWS host machine when in production

Comment: yes that's correct. I left my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compose file creates a docker network. You're running "web" in a container on that network. All containers in the docker network can access other containers via the hostname. However, the browser is running on your host machine. Your host machine is not in the docker network. Therefore your browser won't be able to access the api container via the hostname. If you type `http://api:4505/user/sign-in` into the browser url bar, it's doing the same thing, and you'll also get an error.

Comment: Many thanks for this enligthment! I was running an App with Docker Compose made of FE, BE, and DB, and it kept failing, and I was not understanding at all why the Front-End Typescript code was unable to hit the BackEnd because any terminal session to my FrondEnd with curl or wget was showing that the Front End was indeed fully able to reach the backEnd... so what? Bang! Of course, the Typescript code in question is laying within Vue.js components and then executed from the ... Browser! and with CORS in the path... of course.... configuring CORS on the API BackEnd unlocked the issue. Thanks